# What is difference between "mir gegenüber" and "gegen mich"?

Tags: usage, preposition

In following sample, I'm not sure if I could also use "gegen mich"?

Are **gegenüber mir** and **gegen mich** equivalent?

> Mir gegenüber war er immer sehr höflich.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, they mean different things.

**gegenüber mir** (I would prefer the reverse order **mir gegenüber** as in your example) means *towards me* (e.g. in the sense “They are well-disposed towards me”, in German: „Sie sind mir gegenüber wohlgesinnt.“).

**gegen mich**, however, means *against me* (e.g. in the sense “He voted against me”, in German: „Er hat gegen mich gestimmt.“).

Also note that in the first example we use the dative („mir“) whereas in the second example we use the accusative („mich“).

Answer (score 2):

Ja, man kann es sagen, aber es ist nicht mehr üblich.

Beleg: Karl Kraus, Die Sprache:

> Wo sich mir einmal der Spalt zwischen Wort und Wesen auftat, da konnte
>   ich mit Stolz sagen, daß der Ephialtes ein Muster der Nibelungentreue
>   gegen mich gewesen ist.

Die Bedeutung ist auch hier 'mir gegenüber', denn Treue ist ja kein Merkmal einer feindlichen Gesinnung.